# pytorch Geometric: RandomLinkSplit getting error

Tags: python, train-test-split, pytorch-geometric

I have data from Amazon Review Dataset. I cleaned the data and create Heterogeneous graph data with pytorch geometric.
I want to convert the data into train, test and validation sets using pythorch geometric and getting error message!
[image]

[image]